# Background sync of content

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I'm interested in a PWA implementation for a news/publishing website, and one of the key points is the background sync.

I'd like to get some clarifications on a few scenarios - I hope you can help.

**Scenario 1**:

1. I have my phone on - with 4G/WiFi connection over night and the PWA is **closed**
2. During that time, 4 new articles are published on the site
3. I grab my phone *without* opening the PWA
4. I get on the tube, and there's no connection
5. I open the PWA

**Expected outcome**: the 4 new articles are **not displayed** in the PWA

--

**Scenario 2**:

1. I have my phone on - with 4G/WiFi connection over night and the PWA is **open** in the background
2. During that time, 4 new articles are published on the site
3. I get on the tube, and there's no connection
4. I open the PWA

**Expected outcome**: the 4 new articles **are displayed** in the PWA

--

Can you please confirm that's what I would expect ?

Many thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Scenario 1** is correct. You won't see the new articles.
However in the future, this might be possible with the [Periodic Sync API](https://github.com/WICG/BackgroundSync/blob/master/explainer.md#periodic-synchronization-in-design) which is currently being spec'ed.

**Scenario 2** I don't think that's correct, as your page will be `frozen` once you navigate away (whether to another tab, or if you go back to your homescreen). So I don't think a `setInterval` would run when the page is not **focused** (aka open).

For the future, this will be solved too with the Periodic Sync API as your app doesn't need to be open at all for the Periodic sync to run (note: it might change, or it might not even be supported by any browser)